# How to link gfortran when I compile?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, compilation

I use ubuntu 12.04, my Makefile FC:gfortran, but I couldn't compile, 
I checked on it, it installed(my gcc upgraded from 4.6.3 to 4.7)
How do I link to it?

I tried pkg-config --cflags --lib gfortran or gtkxxx, it says not in the pkg_config_path

I checked gfortran: COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' -with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu

Comment: Please format code or commands appropriately (each line starts with four spaces)

Comment: How do I reinstall it to link properly, it's not in the pgk_config_path.

Comment: -1: the question is badly asked (it looks like how to link GTK into a Fortran library, and there is no mention of failing commands!) and badly formatted. Please *edit the question* to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `pkg-config` to use `gfortran`; you just need to compile and link with the `gfortran` executable (and you can also use `gfortran` to link C code with Fortran code, and you could probably link using `gcc` with `-lgfortran`)

BTW, `pkg-config` accepts the `--list-all` option; with the command

```
pkg-config --list-all |grep -i gtk
```

you can understand that GTK is in fact `gtk+-x11-3.0`

You should also read the [documentation of GFORTRAN](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/); it has a chapter about [mixed-language-programming](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Mixed-Language-Programming.html)

Of course you need to install the `gfortran`, `gfortran-4.7` and `libgfortran-4.7-dev` packages

Comment: I tried to link with gcc -lgfortran, it says: 
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status